# GridDB Error Code 30001 (CP_WRITE_HANDLER_FAILED) - Backup or Checkpoint Execution Failure

Tags: python, installation, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I am currently grappling with an issue in my GridDB implementation and am seeking assistance to resolve it.

```
store = factory.get_store(
    cluster_name,
    notification_member,
    data_member,
    username,
    password
)

# Attempt to perform a backup or checkpoint
store.checkpoint()
```

Error Details:

Error Code: 30001
Error Message: CP_WRITE_HANDLER_FAILED
Description: Backup or checkpoint execution failed.
This error surfaces when attempting to perform a backup or checkpoint in my GridDB setup. The error message suggests that the failure may be associated with issues in the storage at the data file storage location. It's worth noting that I am using a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

In an attempt to address the problem, I've checked for empty space in the database file storage location. Additionally, I've investigated the possibility of a physical failure.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I would appreciate any guidance or insights on additional steps I should take to troubleshoot and resolve this GridDB error. Are there specific checks or configurations I should examine to identify and address the root cause of the CP_WRITE_HANDLER_FAILED error?

Thank you in advance for your support and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think store.checkpoint() is a valid GridDB method. are you sure you're doing something that exists?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment.